# How I can make alarm on off?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I want to do is BEEP! to show that the program is running.

```
#define SPKR 4 //this is the digital pin that you plugged the red       wire into

void setup()
{
   pinMode(SPKR, OUTPUT); //set the speaker as output
}

void loop() //do this over and over
{
   digitalWrite(SPKR, HIGH); //turn the speaker on
   delay(500);                     //wait for half a second
   digitalWrite(SPKR, LOW); //turn the speaker off
   delay(500);                    //wait for half a second
}
```

With out this any other way
I mean without repeating the code HIGH / LOW
during this beep I want do same things else

Comment: I don't understand your question. I guess English isn't your first language. Can you find another way to explain it please?

Comment: you code works well as-is with an "active buzzer" module.

Answer (score 2):

The code you show will toggle the `SPKR` pin at a 1 Hz rate.  If you have an ordinary speaker attached, you will hear it click twice a second, but it won't generate an audible tone.

To generate a tone, use [`tone(pin, frequency)`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone) calls, or `tone(pin, frequency, duration)` calls.

For example:

```
void loop() {
   tone(SPKR, 400, 500); // 400 Hz tone for half second
   delay(500);           // no tone for half second
}
```

Note, ordinary speakers are low-impedance devices, eg 4 Ω, 8 Ω, etc.  You can use an audio transformer for impedance matching – this helps produce an adequate output volume – but lacking that, should put a resistor (eg 220 Ω) in series with the speaker to avoid over-current conditions.  AVR pins can deliver 25 mA without too much stress, and typically are rated at an absolute max of 40 mA.